# Filter by comma-separated data

Tags: c#, filter, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My website posts have tags created to classify the posts. I am using the tags to create a tag filter for the posts. [StackOverflow tags section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) as an example.

I am using the [MSSQL database](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql) column that stores multiple row IDs separated by comma(s).

Here is an example:

| Id | Title | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | Title 2 | 3,4,7 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to split them using comma in my Controller Action, but I am facing some issues:

Controller action method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    var taggedPosts = from p in _context.Posts select p;

    taggedPosts = taggedPosts.Where(p => int.Parse(p.Tags) == id);
    
    var Tags = new DetailTagsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = await taggedPosts.ToListAsync()
    };

    return View(Tags);
}
```

I have tried separating `p.Tags` using `.Split(',')` but it doesn't work.

Here is what I have tried:

- Creating a new variable `splitTags`:

```cs
var splitTags = from p in _context.Posts select p.Tags.Split(',');
```

Gives error:

1. **CS0854** - An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments.
2. **CS8602** - Dereference of a possibly null reference.

- Modifying variable `taggedPosts`:

```cs
taggedPosts = taggedPosts.Where(p => p.Tags.Split(',').Select(int.Parse) == id);
```

Gives error:

1. **CS0019** - Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type `IEnumerable<int>` and `int`
2. **CS8602** - Dereference of a possibly null reference.

Comment: Your question is unclear without specifying what you are trying to achieve and the expected output. From my understanding (if I am not wrong), you are finding the related post of selected post. Have you tried: `taggedPosts = taggedPosts.Where(p => p.Tags.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Contains(id));`?

Comment: Also please mention which DB you are using. MSSQL, Postgres, etc.

Comment: @YongShun I tried your suggested code. It gave the following errors to `p.Tags.Split(',')`: **CS8602**  and **CS0854**.

Comment: You didn't follow my code, `.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Contains(id)` but not `.Select(int.Parse) == id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt that there is no support for converting `String.Split()` into SQL expression in Entity Framework Core/LINQ.

The only way to achieve by fetching the records from the database and performing filtering on the memory side. This may sacrifice the query performance as it will fetch all the records from the database.

The concept for filtering:

1. Split `Tags` by comma (',') and result in an array of strings.
2. Convert the array of strings to an array of integers.
3. Evaluate the `id` existing in the integers via `.Contains()`.

```cs
var taggedPosts = await (from p in _context.Posts select p)
    .ToListAsync();

taggedPosts = taggedPosts.Where(p => p.Tags
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
        .Contains(id))
    .ToList();
    
var Tags = new DetailTagsViewModel
{
    PostCard = taggedPosts
};
```

Comment: Note that the query syntax: `await (from p in _context.Posts select p).ToListAsync()` can be replaced with `await _context.Posts.ToListAsync()`